# play audio files for a particular time interval in c++

Tags: c++, audio

I want to play mp3/wav file of a particular time interval. That means if an audio file is 30 minutes long then i want to play from 10 minutes to 20 minutes (or 15min to 30min) of that file in c++ like audio slicing. but i just want to play. is it possible? can anyone guide me?

Comment: [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/), [libav](https://libav.org/).

Answer (score 0):

C++ itself has no knowledge of sound/audio, you'll have to use a 3rd party library written for this sort of thing.  XAudio in windows I believe, may have a new name now (used to be DirectSound), or other Miles Sound System, etc.